# Laravel AWS S3 Image Streaming view

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

How can I get AWS S3 image as streaming view?

Now I can see image as following url:

```
<img src="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/image.png" />
```

I want to get like this:

```
<img src="https://myproject.com/upload/image.png" />
```

I tried as following but it didn't work.
My route:

```
Route::get('/upload/{path_to_image}', 'FileController@getImage')->where('path', '(.*)');
```

-My Controller

```
    public function getImage($disk, $path)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/image',
        );
        if(Storage::disk("s3")->exists($path))
        {
            $file = Storage::disk("s3")->path($path);
            return response()->file($file, $headers);
        }
        abort(404);
    }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: I didn't understand, do you want to use your own url instead of S3 url, or is there some other issue? (I'm an AWS developer and know a bit about laravel).

Comment: Yes, I want my own url instead of AWS url.

Comment: "it didn't work" is pretty broad. What does that **exactly** mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution is based on AWS.**

Use CloudFront (CDN) with custom domain name to use your own url in place of S3 URL.

- Create a CloudFront distribution and attach it to your S3 bucket.
- Allow only HTTPS requests in Viewer Protocol Policy.
- For alternate domain names (CNAMEs) type your custom domain.
- Provide the SSL Certificate for your domain.

You can follow [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20CloudFront%20console.,your%20S3%20bucket%27s%20website%20endpoint.) for detailed steps.

Once the distribution is available, you can access S3 files with your domain url, e.g. `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/path/to/image.png` can be accessed as `https://myproject.com/image.png`.

If you want to use some custom path for images, e.g. `/upload/image.png` you can use a [Behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior) and specify that path.

Please read [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) to know more about CloudFront and how it can optimize your web responses.